# Different in behavior between input and textarea

Tags: html, textarea

I have a little question regarding different control types  in html.

In my application I'm using both simple input text and textarea. I've noticed some difference between them: when navigating between the controls with TAB key - all the text in the input field is selected on focus, while in textarea the cursor is placed in the beginning of the text. (see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WyyO58ikqCxR7kGgSmaY?p=preview))

```
 <input type="text" value="I am simple input"/>
 <textarea text="I am text area" ></textarea>
```

I want the input to behave like the textarea. What's the way to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

*A text area should have a  specified height and width:*

---

**Syntax:-**

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
Yes, I am doing HTML coding, Do you enjoy It.
</textarea>
```

Comment: I didn't understand how this is supposed to solve my problem... My question was - how can I force the input to behave like the textarea (do not select all text on focus but display the cursor at the beginning of the text)

Answer (score 0):

For tab you need this

```
<textarea id='foo' >Some Text</textarea>

 $("#foo").on("focus keyup", function (e) {

            var keycode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which ? e.which : e.charCode;
            if (keycode === 9 || !keycode) {
                // Hacemos select
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.select();

                // Para Chrome's que da problema
                $this.on("mouseup", function () {
                    // Unbindeamos el mouseup
                    $this.off("mouseup");
                    return false;
                });
            }
        });
```

You can try this as you are using javascript for mouse focus

```
<textarea id="foo">Some text</textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var textBox = document.getElementById("foo");
    textBox.onfocus = function() {
    textBox.select();

    // Work around Chrome's little problem
    textBox.onmouseup = function() {
        // Prevent further mouseup intervention
        textBox.onmouseup = null;
        return false;
    };
};
```

but we can use jquery also for the same.

Comment: Thanks, it might solve the problem for a specific textarea, however in my case I want the **input** to behave like the textarea and not the other way around like your example show.